# How can I get the id of a selected item in a list using the the dropdownSearch widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I am using the DropDownSearch widget in flutter to display a list of items. I am displaying the value "acYear" from the list but I want to be able to pass the value "id" of the selected item to the controller i.e academicYearController.text .How can I achieve this please? This is what I have tried:

```js
child: DropdownSearch < dynamic > (
  autoValidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
  validator: (value) =>
  value == null ? "Academic Year is required " : null,
  dropdownDecoratorProps: const DropDownDecoratorProps(
      dropdownSearchDecoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: "Select academic year",
        helperText: '',
        labelText: "Academic Year *",
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 12, 0, 0),
        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
      ),
    ),
    items: dataService.academicYearList.map((AcademicYear yr) {
      return yr.accYear.toString();
    }).toList(),
    // items: dataService.academicYearList.map((AcademicYear yr) {
    //   return DropdownMenuItem(
    //     child: Text(yr.id.toString()),
    //     value: yr.id,
    //   );
    // }).toList(),
    onChanged: (value) {
      academicYearController.text = value;
      setState(() {
        dataService.selectedAcademicYear = dataService.selected;
      });
      debugPrint('selectedId: ${academicYearController.text}');
    },
),
```

And the AcademicYear Object and academicYear List look like this:

```js
class AcademicYear {
  int id;
  String accYearId;
  String accYear;
  int status;

  AcademicYear({
    required this.id,
    required this.accYearId,
    required this.accYear,
    required this.status,
  });

  [{
    "id": 1,
    "accYearId": "20212022",
    "accYear": "20212022",
    "status": 1
  }]
```

I have Added the API call to get the academicYear data just incase am doing something wrong as shown:

```js
Future < List < AcademicYear >> getYears() async {
  academicUrl = "${dataService.baseUrl}/academicyear";
  // debugPrint('url: $academicUrl');

  http.Response response = await http.get(
    Uri.parse(academicUrl),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  );

  List < AcademicYear > result(dynamic str) => List < AcademicYear > .from(
    json.decode(str).map((x) => AcademicYear.fromJson(x)));

  // debugPrint('result: ${response.body}');

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return result(response.body);
  } else {
    throw Exception('error loading object');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `DropdownSearch's` onChanged , do this:

```
onChanged: (value) {
      var xList = dataService.academicYearList.where((element) => element.accYear == value);

      if (xList.isNotEmpty) {
         AcademicYear x = xList.first;
         print("x = ${x.id}");
         academicYearController.text = value;
      }
      
      setState(() {
        dataService.selectedAcademicYear = dataService.selected;
      });
      debugPrint('selectedId: ${academicYearController.text}');
    },
```

Comment: If I do that I get an error on the items: Arrray
The argument type 'List<String>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<AcademicYear>'.

Comment: could you show me sample of your data? are all accYear in your list different with each other?

Comment: Yes they are different e.g
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "accYearId": "20212022",
        "accYear": "20212022",
        "status": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "accYearId": "20222023",
        "accYear": "20222023",
        "status": 1
    }
]

Comment: Could the problem be the way am doing getting my data back from the API? Let me share the service Call to get this data

Comment: I updated my answer, check it out. @Emmon